# Missing perform for selenium ActionChains

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, static-analysis, flake8

It is a very common and, sometimes, difficult to spot problem when "action chains" are defined but not being actually applied. Example:

```
# incorrect
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(some_element).click(some_element)
```

as opposed to:

```
# correct
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(some_element).click(some_element).perform()
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

ActionChains would essentially do nothing and perform no action without `perform()`.

Is there a way to catch this type of a problem early with static code analysis?

---

I've also looked if PyCharm would warn about this, but it reports no suspicious code found which is understandable as without the `perform()` call it is still a perfectly valid Python.

There is also this [`missing-perform` ESLint rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/missing-perform.md).

Comment: perform() is a "sign" that you need to perform a chain of actions in ActionChains, not a single action

Comment: @AtachiShadow thanks, I think I'm not saying that this is a single action :) Thanks.

Comment: ActionChains will not perform a “chain” of events without `perform()`. This is not a problem, this is logic. It's like in SQL `commit` after `execute`

Comment: I am not questioning that, of course. I am asking about ways to detect missing perform and catch early when a developer missed calling perform() on an action chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### perform()

[perform()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.perform) method performs all stored actions.

As per the implementation of [ActionChains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains), `perform()` is just like another method from the *ActionChains* Class like `move_to_element()`, `click()` etc.

Now, *ActionChains* Class is used to automate low level interactions such as mouse movements, mouse button actions, key press, and context menu interactions which are useful for doing complex actions like hover over and drag and drop through *method chaining*.

The documentation clearly mentions, to generate user actions when you call methods for actions on the ActionChains object, the actions are **stored in a queue** in the *ActionChains* object. Finally, when you call `perform(`), the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

So going by this logic, you were pretty correct to point out *...ActionChains would essentially do nothing and perform no action without `perform()`...* and there is no way to catch this type of a problem early with static code analysis.

Even the IDEs, for example *Eclipse*, *PyCharm* or even [Sublime Text3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) a [proprietary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software) [cross-platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform_software) [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) with a [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) [application programming interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) (API) wouldn't warn about this.

As an example *Eclipse* wouldn't complain about the missing `perfrom()`:

[image: no_perform]

But *Eclipse* would complain about *Bad Indentation*:

[image: bad_indentation]

These cases are similar to the classic case of the IDEs not complaining when [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) which should be called with a **tuple** and it is not a function, but actually a class, whose initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the implicit **self**:

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    # .....
    def __init__(self, locator):
        # .....
```

IDE Snapshot:

[image: tuple]

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. Yeah, it's too specific of a thing for existing static code analysis tool, I was thinking of a custom flake8 or pylint rule - will look into it.