# How to find an existing HTML element with python-selenium in a jupyterhub page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have the following construct in a HTML page and I want to select the `li` element (with python-selenium):

```
<li class="p-Menu-item p-mod-disabled" data-type="command" data-command="notebook:run-all-below">
    <div class="p-Menu-itemIcon"></div>
    <div class="p-Menu-itemLabel" style="">Run Selected Cell and All Below</div>
    <div class="p-Menu-itemShortcut" style=""></div>
    <div class="p-Menu-itemSubmenuIcon"></div>
</li>
```

I am using the following xpath:

```
//li[@data-command='notebook:run-all-below']
```

But the element does not seem to be found.

Complete, minimal working example code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab/tree/demo")

# Wait for the page to be loaded
xpath = "//button[@title='Save the notebook contents and create checkpoint']"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 600).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
)
time.sleep(10)
print("Page loaded")

# Find and click on menu "Run"
xpath_run = "//div[text()='Run']"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_run))
)
element.click()
print("Clicked on 'Run'")

# Find and click on menu entry "Run Selected Cell and All Below"
xpath_runall = "//li[@data-command='notebook:run-all-below']"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 600).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_runall))
)
print("Found element 'Run Selected Cell and All Below'")
element.click()
print("Clicked on 'Run Selected Cell and All Below'")

driver.close()
```

Environment:

- MacOS Mojave (10.14.6)
- python 3.8.6
- selenium 3.8.0
- geckodriver 0.26.0

**Addendum**

I have been trying to record the steps with the Firefox "Selenium IDE" add-on which gives the following steps for python:

```
sdriver.get("https://hub.gke2.mybinder.org/user/jupyterlab-jupyterlab-demo-y0bp97e4/lab/tree/demo")
driver.set_window_size(1650, 916)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0)")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lm-mod-active > .lm-MenuBar-itemLabel").click()
```

which, of course, also does not work. With that code lines I get an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .lm-mod-active > .lm-MenuBar-itemLabel
```

Comment: Can you find this element at all with `find_element_by_xpath`? Maybe it's a wrong element to click on and you need some parent element.

Comment: I can find it with `find_element_by_xpath` it seems. But why can't I find the element with the more safe code as in the example?

Comment: The `<li>` contains the class `p-mod-disabled` and the element is **disabled**. Possibly you won't be able to click.

Comment: But I am able to click on that element. 

Just run the example code, and open the page in the inspector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close enough. Factually your entire program had only a single issue as follows:

- The `xpath_runall = "//li[@data-command='notebook:run-all-below']"` doesn't identify the visible element with text as *Run Selected Cell and All Below* uniquely as the first matched element is a **hidden** element.

---

### Additional considerations

Some more optimizations:

- The element identified as `xpath = "//button[@title='Save the notebook contents and create checkpoint']"` is a **clickable** element. So instead of *EC* as `presence_of_element_located()` you can use **`element_to_be_clickable()`**
- Once the element is returned through *EC* as `element_to_be_clickable()` you can invoke the `click()` on the same line.
- The [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) to identify the element with text as *Run Selected Cell and All Below* would be:

  ```
  //li[@data-command='notebook:run-all-below']//div[@class='lm-Menu-itemLabel p-Menu-itemLabel' and text()='Run Selected Cell and All Below']
  ```
- As the [application](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab/tree/demo) is built through [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) you need to use [ActionChains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782016/missing-perform-for-selenium-actionchains/53812686#53812686).

---

### Solution

Your optimized solution will be:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab/tree/demo")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Save the notebook contents and create checkpoint']")))
  print("Page loaded")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Run']"))).click()
  print("Clicked on Run")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-command='notebook:run-all-below']//div[@class='lm-Menu-itemLabel p-Menu-itemLabel' and text()='Run Selected Cell and All Below']")))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
  print("Clicked on Run Selected Cell and All Below")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Page loaded
  Clicked on Run
  Clicked on Run Selected Cell and All Below
  ```

Comment: I don't believe you need `ActionChains`. Once you have `element` clickable, you can just do `element.click()`.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. I find the top-level menu item using full xpath and then click on it. I wait a small amount of time to ensure that the popup menu has appeared and then using an offset from the original menu item I have pre-determined, I move the mouse to that offset and click on what I know to be the correct sub-menu item. In the code below, I first give myself a chance to select a cell:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(300) # wait up to 300 seconds before calls to find elements time out
driver.get('https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab/tree/demo')
driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 0);")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()="Run"]')
elem.click() # click on top-level menu item
time.sleep(.2) # wait for sub-menu to appear
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 224, 182)
# click on sub-menu item:
action.click()
action.perform()
```

**Update: A More Optimal Solution**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(300) # wait up to 300 seconds before calls to find elements time out
driver.get('https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab/tree/demo')
driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 0);")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()="Run"]')
elem.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(.2)
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Run Selected Cell and All Below")]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem2) # sub-menu, however, stays open
# to close the sub-menu menu:
elem.click()
```

Comment: I am sorry, but the script is supposed to work automatically. If a user interaction was required, I would not need to use selenium at all!

Comment: @Alex I think you misunderstand. The problem as I understand was how to select the Menu Item "Run Selected Cell and All Below", which I took great pains to solve for you. The "manual" code I included was for my testing purposes to first select a particular code cell so that when the menu item was ultimately clicked there would be a selected cell to actually run. I did not think that first selecting a cell to run was part of your problem description. I have removed the `input` statement as it seems to have confused you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your solution seems to work now, but using coordinates to find an element is suboptimal. A small change in the UI or the CSS can inadvertently change these coordinates.

Comment: I've added another solution that should be more to your liking, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are two li elements with similar attributes. You need to identify correct element to click.Use following `xpath` to click on the correct element.

```
xpath_runall = "//ul[@class='lm-Menu-content p-Menu-content']//li[@data-command='notebook:run-all-below']"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_runall))
)
elementText=element.text
print("Found element '{}'".format(elementText))
element.click()
print("Clicked on '{}'".format(elementText))
```

Console output:

```
Page loaded
Clicked on 'Run'
Found element 'Run Selected Cell and All Below'
Clicked on 'Run Selected Cell and All Below'
```

Comment: Sorry, but your solution does not seem to work. I get an error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <li class="lm-Menu-item p-Menu-item lm-mod-disabled p-mod-disabled"> could not be scrolled into view`.