# actions.perform() in selenium only works at the first time, than it does nothing. What can be the problem?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, action

The code below is an automated CookieClicker I wrote for experimenting with ActionChains. It's based on a tutorial video, at 9:42. ([Link](https://youtu.be/OISEEL5eBqg?t=582))

When I run this code, the for loop runs down 1000 times but only 1 click happens. Multiple clicks only happen if I remove "#" from the commented line, so I run `actions.click(cookie)` each time. As for the video, that one extra line of code is not necessary. What can be the cause of that?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

s = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

cookie=driver.find_element(By.ID,"bigCookie")
cookie_count = driver.find_element(By.ID,"cookies")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(cookie)

for i in range(1000):
    #actions.click(cookie)
    actions.perform()
    count=int(cookie_count.text.split(" ")[0])
    print(i,count)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [The ActionChains implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

ActionChains can be used in a chain pattern. When you call methods for actions on the ActionChains object, the actions are stored in a queue in the ActionChains object. When you call [*`perform()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69963527/actionchains-double-click-method-does-not-performs-the-double-click-using-sele/69963792#69963792), the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

---

### [perform()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.perform)

Performs all stored actions.

---

### Conclusion

[*`perform()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782016/missing-perform-for-selenium-actionchains/53812686#53812686) would fire the events stored in the queue. In your usecase, the `actions.click(cookie)` is the event.

Your optimal code block will be:

```
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")
cookie_count = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cookies")))
cookie = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bigCookie")))
for i in range(100):
    ActionChains(driver).click(cookie).perform()
    count = cookie_count.text.split(" ")[0]
    print(i,count)
driver.quit()
```

Console Output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
11 11
12 12
13 13
14 14
15 15
16 16
17 17
18 18
19 19
20 20
21 21
22 22
23 23
24 24
25 25
26 26
27 27
28 28
29 29
30 30
31 31
32 32
33 33
34 34
35 35
36 36
37 37
38 38
39 39
40 40
41 41
42 42
43 43
44 44
45 45
46 46
47 47
48 48
49 49
50 50
51 51
52 52
53 53
54 54
55 55
56 56
57 57
58 58
59 59
60 60
61 61
62 62
63 63
64 64
65 65
66 66
67 67
68 68
69 69
70 70
71 71
72 72
73 73
74 74
75 75
76 76
77 77
78 78
79 79
80 80
81 81
82 82
83 83
84 84
85 85
86 86
87 87
88 88
89 89
90 90
91 91
92 92
93 93
94 94
95 95
96 96
97 97
98 98
99 99
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about using `actions.perform()` like this:  1.
`actions = ActionChains(driver).click(cookie)` ... than 2. 
`actions.perform()` ... this time it works.  Than 3.
`actions.perform()` again ... but this time it does nothing. Why?

Comment: Please pay attention to the first line of the conclusion and additionally the minor (but significant) change in the lines of code.

Comment: @mgergo You may be right, I haven't seen the video but several of my _`ActionChains()`_ and _`perform()`_ related long posts following the _Selenium_ documentation and best practices were beneficial to the community members.

Comment: @mgergo Absolutely, you have hit the right chord.

Comment: [accidentally deleted]: Ok, thank you. I got it. So using `.perform()` empties the queue of events. Maybe the behavior of `ActionChains()` has been changed since the video was made.

Comment: @mgergo Honestly, I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using actions, for the sake of using it, or learning about it, since you could simply call `cookie.click()` to get the desired result.

Actions are used when you need to perform some "action" to an element other than find it or click on it, i.e. you want to right click, or click and hold, or send a keystroke combination and so on. Check [Selenium Actions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) for more info.

As for using actions to click, you need to also understand that perform gets the composite object (call the build function of Actions) of your actions and execute them. Since your actions are declared outside the for loop, after the first click, the `perform()` function has no more actions to perform.

TLDR:

Either remove the comment of `actions.click(cookie)` inside your for loop or use `cookie.click()` to get the same result without using actions.

```
for i in range(10):
    actions.click(cookie)
    actions.perform()
    #cookie.click()
    count=int(cookie_count.text.split(" ")[0])
    print(i,count)

driver.quit()
```

[Colab Notebook of it working](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K_9BfuzKAR2jCE6e2kpfY5EBqRlW8bBj?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question, to be more clear. The thing I don't understand is why the code runs properly in the mentioned video WITHOUT the `actions.click(cookie)` line in the for loop. (At 9:42, [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OISEEL5eBqg&t=582s) ) It just looks controversial.

Comment: @mgergo please read the whole answer. The answer to your comment is in the last sentence of the second paragraph

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, the behavior of `ActionChains()` must have changed since the linked video was made.